# Getting return boolean value from the function in perl

Tags: perl

I heard from multiple tutorials that there is no Boolean variable. Instead I can use 1 for true or 0 for false. However, I have 2 methods to get the boolean values. The output is the same.. But I do not know which method is correct for collecting the return boolean values.
Let me give you an example
I made a script,call.pl to call the function from another script,script.pl and the script.pl will return the 1 or 0. I perform the if conditional to evaluate.
If it is true, it will says that it is even otherwise it is odd.

Method 1
script.pl

```
sub checkevenodd {
     my ($num) = @_;
     chomp($num);
     my $remainder = $num % 2;
     if ($remainder == 0)
     {
       return 1;
     }
     else
     {
        return 0
     }
}
1;
```

call.pl

```
require "script.pl";
my $no = 123;
if (checkevenodd($no) == 1)
{
    print "it is even";
}
else
{
   print "it is odd";
}
```

method 2
script.pl

```
sub checkevenodd {
     my ($num) = @_;
     chomp($num);
     my $remainder = $num % 2;
     if ($remainder == 0)
     {
       return 1;
     }
     else
     {
        return 0
     }
}
1;
```

call.pl

```
require "script.pl";
my $no = 123;
if (checkevenodd($no))
{
    print "it is even";
}
else
{
   print "it is odd";
}
```

I use the function to check whether is it 1 or 0... Then if it is 1, it is even or else odd.
So which method is best for receiving the boolean value from the function?? I do not want to create a variable. Instead I want to return 1 or 0.. How to get the 1 or 0.. Is it correct method??

Comment: Zero and one are considered false and true respectively. So you can simply use the short form: `if (checkevenodd($no)) {...}`. I think this implicit form is also more correct, since you are actually checking if the condition is true or false, and not comparing integers.

Comment: 0 is false, but 1 is not exactly true, it is just one possible value for true. True is everything not being false. For example 2 is also true.

Comment: @ceving, 0 is just one of many false values as well.

Comment: Having the subroutine in a different file is a complete red herring here. It has nothing to do with the problem at all.

Comment: i dont understand on why is there no boolean variable in perl but other programming have that

Comment: @Azhar: Because (to a first approximation, at least) Perl has no typed variables at all. There are no integer variables, no floating point variables, no string variables. Why would we then want to create Boolean variables?

Comment: I mean $var refer to scalar variable, @array refer to the array % refers to the hash.

Comment: @Azhar: And Booleans are scalars - as they are a single piece of information.

Comment: @Azhar, Re "*i dont understand on why is there no boolean variable in perl*", Because Perl is built around scalars. You can only pass scalars to subs. Subs can only return scalars. `if` checks a scalar. `foreach` iterates over scalars. etc, etc, etc, etc. Having a new type of variable would greatly increase the language's complexity with no benefit.

Comment: @Azhar, OTOH, If you might be asking: Why Perl doesn't have boolean values `true` and `false`? Because it wouldn't help. What should `if ($foo)` do when it's neither `true` nor `false`? Well, the way Perl handles cases like these everywhere else is that Perl automatically converts the values with the wrong type into the correct type (e.g. `"abc"+"def"` is equivalent to `0+0`). That means `if ($foo)` would automatically transform `$foo` into `true` or `false` if they're not already, so you'd get exactly the same behaviour as you get today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write:

```
if (checkevenodd($no) == 1)
```

You are not checking for a Boolean value. You are checking for the value 1. In this case it will work (because `checkevenodd()` only ever returns 0 or 1) but, in general, you should only ever check the truth of a Boolean expression, not its value. It's much better to write:

```
if (checkevenodd($no))
```

A couple of other points.

- `checkevenodd` is not a good name for this subroutine. When I have subroutines that return Boolean values, I always try to give them a name that starts with `is_`. Your subroutine returns true if the number is even, so I would call this subroutine `is_even()`.
- Your subroutine is far more complex than it needs to be. I would write it as:

  ```
  sub is_even {
    my ($num) = @_;

    # For an even number, $num % 2 is zero - which is false.
    # Therefore use ! to make it true.
    return ! $num % 2;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
sub even_odd {
     my ($num) = @_;
     my $remainder = $num % 2;
     return $remainder ? 0 : 1;

}
```

and using it as a complete script:

```
my $no = 123;
if (even_odd($no))
{
    print "it is even";
}
else
 {
   print "it is odd";
}

sub even_odd {
     my ($num) = @_;
     my $remainder = $num % 2;
     return $remainder ? 0 : 1;

}
```

returns: it is odd